# How to merge and convert list of tuples to Dict

Tags: python, dictionary, tuples

I have two lists of tuples. One list has unique elements the other does not. I need to merge and convert them. See example below:

```
non_unique = [('A',2), ('B',3), ('C',4), ('D',5), ('E',6), ('A',8), ('C', 5), ('E',1) ]

unique = [('A',5), ('B',4), ('C',2)]
```

The `non_unique` has repeated `A`, `C`, `E`. But I'm interested in merging (adding corresponding digits in )  `non_unique` only if same non-digit appear in `unique`. Digits in `unique` are not used. Therefore, A, B, C in `unique` gives the dict:

```
    result = {'A': 10, 'B': 3, 'C': 9}
```

I'm not sure what steps I should use to obtain this result. Any tip would be helpful.

Comment: You should try to solve it before asking. If you have already tried anything, just post it.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Start by declaring both of your lists of tuples

```
non_unique = [('A',2), ('B',3), ('C',4), ('D',5), ('E',6), ('A',8), ('C', 5), ('E',1) ]

unique = [('A',5), ('B',4), ('C',2)]
```

Then create a new dictionary from the unique keys, with starting values of `0`

```
d = {key: 0 for (key, value) in unique}
```

Then iterate through each tuple in `non_unique`, checking if the key already exists.  If the key does exist, add the value to the existing value in the dictionary.

```
for (k, v) in non_unique:
    if k in d:
        d[k] += v
```

Full Code:

```
non_unique = [('A',2), ('B',3), ('C',4), ('D',5), ('E',6), ('A',8), ('C', 5), ('E',1) ]

unique = [('A',5), ('B',4), ('C',2)]

d = {key: 0 for (key, value) in unique}

print(d)

for (k, v) in non_unique:
    if k in d:
        d[k] += v

print(d)
```

Comment: Thank you for the breakdown.

Answer (score 0):

```
d = {a[0]: sum( [tup[1] for tup in non_unique if tup[0] == a[0]]) for a in unique}
```